# Can I create notifications when an Atlassian Confluence page is created?

Tags: rest, webhooks, confluence, confluence-rest-api

If any user changes or creates new page in Atlassian Confluence, I would like to automatically send a REST request. I want to use it for pushing auto-messages in messenger (in some public channel). It is useful to see any new changes on wiki.

I found info about REST API for Atlassian Confluence:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/

But it is about how to sent requests to Confluence.

**Is it possible to generate auto requests from Atlassian Confluence?**

---

**Update:** I found some information - looks like it is impossible. 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-52487
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, unfortunately this functionality does not exist at the moment. The best way would be to write your own Confluence Plugin that binds to certain events. See https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/event-listener-module/ for more information about this. Then you can send the desired requests to your messenger every time the event occurs.

Another option, but unfortunately not free, would be the "Script Runner for Confluence" plugin. This plugin provides at least a simpler way for the above solution. You only have to implement the "send request" part, as the event handling is done by the plugin and can be configured via UI. See http://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/confluencecloud/script-listeners.html#_set_a_watcher_for_new_blog_posts for more information.